# JPA @OneToMany & @ManyToOne null

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with ManyToOne relation.

These are my entities:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * A Product.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("")
    private Supplier supplier;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("")
    private Tax tax;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private Set<Combination> combinations = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private Set<ProductImages> images = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private Set<ProductTranslate> translates = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productIds")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Category> categoryIds = new HashSet<>();


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public Supplier getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    public Product supplier(Supplier supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
        return this;
    }

    public void setSupplier(Supplier supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public Tax getTax() {
        return tax;
    }

    public Product tax(Tax tax) {
        this.tax = tax;
        return this;
    }

    public void setTax(Tax tax) {
        this.tax = tax;
    }

    public Set<Combination> getCombinations() {
        return combinations;
    }

    public Product combinations(Set<Combination> combinations) {
        this.combinations = combinations;
        return this;
    }

    public Product addCombinations(Combination combination) {
        this.combinations.add(combination);
        combination.setProduct(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Product removeCombinations(Combination combination) {
        this.combinations.remove(combination);
        combination.setProduct(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setCombinations(Set<Combination> combinations) {
        this.combinations = combinations;
    }

    public Set<ProductImages> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public Product images(Set<ProductImages> productImages) {
        this.images = productImages;
        return this;
    }

    public Product addImages(ProductImages productImages) {
        this.images.add(productImages);
        productImages.setProduct(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Product removeImages(ProductImages productImages) {
        this.images.remove(productImages);
        productImages.setProduct(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setImages(Set<ProductImages> productImages) {
        this.images = productImages;
    }

    public Set<ProductTranslate> getTranslates() {
        return translates;
    }

    public Product translates(Set<ProductTranslate> productTranslates) {
        this.translates = productTranslates;
        return this;
    }

    public Product addTranslates(ProductTranslate productTranslate) {
        this.translates.add(productTranslate);
        productTranslate.setProduct(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Product removeTranslates(ProductTranslate productTranslate) {
        this.translates.remove(productTranslate);
        productTranslate.setProduct(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setTranslates(Set<ProductTranslate> productTranslates) {
        this.translates = productTranslates;
    }

    public Set<Category> getCategoryIds() {
        return categoryIds;
    }

    public Product categoryIds(Set<Category> categories) {
        this.categoryIds = categories;
        return this;
    }

    public Product addCategoryId(Category category) {
        this.categoryIds.add(category);
        category.getProductIds().add(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Product removeCategoryId(Category category) {
        this.categoryIds.remove(category);
        category.getProductIds().remove(this);
        return this;
    }

    public void setCategoryIds(Set<Category> categories) {
        this.categoryIds = categories;
    }

}
```

And:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * A ProductImages.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_images")
public class ProductImages implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "is_default")
    private Boolean isDefault;

    @Column(name = "url")
    private String url;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("images")
    private Product product;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean isIsDefault() {
        return isDefault;
    }

    public ProductImages isDefault(Boolean isDefault) {
        this.isDefault = isDefault;
        return this;
    }

    public void setIsDefault(Boolean isDefault) {
        this.isDefault = isDefault;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public ProductImages url(String url) {
        this.url = url;
        return this;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public ProductImages product(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
        return this;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

Now when I try to send get all products request I expect to get all images also. But I get null.

Here is my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT p FROM " +
        "Product p WHERE p.insertDate > ?1 ORDER BY p.insertDate DESC")
    Page<Product> findFeatured(ZonedDateTime inserDate, Pageable pageable);
}
```

In my database table have records:

```
ID, price, stock, manifacture_id, supplier_id, tax_id, weight, weight_unit, width, height, depth, lenght_unit, status, insert_date, priority
'1', '12.10', '10', '1', NULL, NULL, '2', 'KG', '22.1', '12.4', '3', 'CM', 'ACTIVE', '2018-08-01 00:00:00', '0'
```

Product Images table:

```
ID, product_id, is_default, url
1, 1, 0, dfsdfsdfs
2, 1, 0, jghjjggj
```

I did everything but can't found solution.

When I check sql on request:

```
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_10_0_, product0_.depth as depth2_10_0_, product0_.height as height3_10_0_, product0_.insert_date as insert_d4_10_0_, product0_.lenght_unit as lenght_u5_10_0_, product0_.manifacture_id as manifact6_10_0_, product0_.price as price7_10_0_, product0_.priority as priority8_10_0_, product0_.status as status9_10_0_, product0_.stock as stock10_10_0_, product0_.supplier_id as supplie14_10_0_, product0_.tax_id as tax_id15_10_0_, product0_.weight as weight11_10_0_, product0_.weight_unit as weight_12_10_0_, product0_.width as width13_10_0_, supplier1_.id as id1_13_1_, supplier1_.about as about2_13_1_, supplier1_.birthdate as birthdat3_13_1_, supplier1_.email as email4_13_1_, supplier1_.name as name5_13_1_, supplier1_.overall_raiting as overall_6_13_1_, supplier1_.password as password7_13_1_, supplier1_.status as status8_13_1_, supplier1_.surname as surname9_13_1_, tax2_.id as id1_15_2_, tax2_.is_active as is_activ2_15_2_, tax2_.name as name3_15_2_, tax2_.percentage as percenta4_15_2_ from product product0_ left outer join supplier supplier1_ on product0_.supplier_id=supplier1_.id left outer join tax tax2_ on product0_.tax_id=tax2_.id where product0_.id=?
```

Here is the result:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "price": 12.1,
  "stock": 10,
  "manifactureId": 1,
  "weight": 2,
  "weightUnit": "KG",
  "width": 22.1,
  "height": 12.4,
  "depth": 3,
  "lenghtUnit": "CM",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "insertDate": "2018-08-01T00:00:00+04:00",
  "priority": 0,
  "supplier": null,
  "tax": null,
  "combinations": null,
  "images": null,
  "translates": null
}
```

Do anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default value for `fetchType` in `@OneToMany` is `FetchType.LAZY`.

make it `EAGER` fetch.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "product")
```

You'll find one `join` in the query for picking images.

[@OneToMany](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
// If your result need images,you can call getImages()
// Product your get
product.getImages()
```

Then the getting images Sql will be executed.

If your result don't need images,you don't call `getImages()`

If using `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`,your result always has images in product.

Comment: By default, single point associations are eagerly fetched in JPA 2. You can mark it as lazily fetched by using @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) in which case Hibernate will proxy the association and load it when the state of the associated entity is reached. -- [Hibernate manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e3742)

Comment: Actually this solution is much more smart. But for call getImages() every time I use foreach after repository query.